# Different sort option for single result set in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data set as follows, result of select *,

```
Event Id|Event Status|Start_Date
1       | ongoing    |    Date  
4       | ongoing    |    Date  
3       | resolved   |    Date  
5       | upcoming   |    Date  
2       | upcoming   |    Date
```

Now I want event status with ongoing & resolved needs to be 'ordered by Start_Date desc'.
upcoming with 'ordered by Start_Date asc'

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data (and replace "Date" with an actual date value). [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

try this order

```
order by 
(case when Event_Status in ('ongoing','resolved ') then Start_Date else null end) desc,
(case when Event_Status in ('upcoming') then Start_Date else null end) asc;
```